# How to get next and previous value from an Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need one help. I have an json object which contains some value and I need to find next id and previous id as per some user input value using Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
var data = [{
    "parentdes": "Parent description1",
    "parentid":"1",
    "childdes": [{
      "des": 'chile description11',
      "childid":"11",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des111',
        "sub_sub_id":"111"
      },{
        "des": 'subchild des444',
        "sub_sub_id":"444"
      },{
        "des": 'subchild des555',
        "sub_sub_id":"555"
      }]
    }, {
      "des": 'chile description12',
      "childid":"12",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des112',
        "sub_sub_id":"112"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "parentdes": "Parent description2",
    "parentid":"2",
    "childdes": [{
      "des": 'chile description21',
      "childid":"21",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des212',
        "sub_sub_id":"212"
      }]
    }, {
      "des": 'chile description22',
      "childid":"22",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des222',
        "sub_sub_id":"222"
      }]
    }]
  }];
```

Here I have an array which contains Json value like `parent-child-subchild` . Suppose user has input like `"sub_sub_id":"444"` and here I need to fetch the `next sub_sub_id and previous sub_sub_id` if both is available then there should be also `isNext=true and isPrevious=true` will detect along with both id. In this case the output should be like this `nextid=555 and previd=111` and `isNext=true and isPrevious=true`. Similarly if user input is i.e-`"sub_sub_id":"111"` then the output should be `nextid=444and previd=''` and `isNext=true and isPrevious=false` like this again if user input is i.e-`"sub_sub_id":"555"` then the output should be `nextid=112and previd=444` and `isNext=true and isPrevious=true`. Please help me.

Comment: You could wrap the data in an object with getters added.

Comment: Can you please solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works, you can call `getInfo` with the ID and you will get the `prev` and `next` id

**Edit:** Updated code to not sort the element (mistaken)

```js
    var data = [{
        "parentdes": "Parent description1",
        "parentid":"1",
        "childdes": [{
          "des": 'chile description11',
          "childid":"11",
          "subchilddes": [{
            "des": 'subchild des111',
            "sub_sub_id":"111"
          },{
            "des": 'subchild des444',
            "sub_sub_id":"444"
          },{
            "des": 'subchild des555',
            "sub_sub_id":"555"
          }]
        }, {
          "des": 'chile description12',
          "childid":"12",
          "subchilddes": [{
            "des": 'subchild des112',
            "sub_sub_id":"112"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "parentdes": "Parent description2",
        "parentid":"2",
        "childdes": [{
          "des": 'chile description21',
          "childid":"21",
          "subchilddes": [{
            "des": 'subchild des212',
            "sub_sub_id":"212"
          }]
        }, {
          "des": 'chile description22',
          "childid":"22",
          "subchilddes": [{
            "des": 'subchild des222',
            "sub_sub_id":"222"
          }]
        }]
      }];


    var index = {},
        prevChild;

    data.forEach(function(parent) {
      parent.childdes.forEach(function(child) {
        child.subchilddes.forEach(function(subchild) {
          if (prevChild) {
            prevChild.__next = subchild;
            subchild.__prev = prevChild;
          }
          index[parseInt(subchild.sub_sub_id, 10)] = subchild;

          prevChild = subchild;
        });
      });
    });

    function getInfo(id) {
      if (index[id]) {
        var res  = {},
            prev = index[id].__prev,
            next = index[id].__next;

        if (prev) res.prevId = prev.sub_sub_id;
        if (next) res.nextId = next.sub_sub_id;
        return res;
      }
    }

    console.log(getInfo(444)); // Print 111 and 555
    console.log(getInfo(555)); // Print 444 and 112
```

Comment: let me to check and let you know ?

Comment: I just reread your question, seems like you want to use the output to run it as a SQL command?

Comment: No,its printing wrong output. input `111` should have next id `444`.

Comment: Cool, if it works you can up vote/accept it as the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic:

1. Iterate over your array and parse the objects structure to a string represting the `sub_sub_id` and it's `value`.
2. If you find a String containing `'sub_sub_id:'` split it and put the value after the ':' in a new array
3. The new array will contain `["111","444","555","112","212","222"]` (it's actually your map of each id, its prev and next value).
4. Using the new array, you can easily check with it's indexes what's the next `sub_sub_id`, what the previous `sub_sub_id` and if each one exists ***(i leave this last part for you to write)***

Here is the code that does that ([and a working codepan](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPBYXQ?editors=1112)):

```
var data = [{
    "parentdes": "Parent description1",
    "parentid":"1",
    "childdes": [{
      "des": 'chile description11',
      "childid":"11",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des111',
        "sub_sub_id":"111"
      },{
        "des": 'subchild des444',
        "sub_sub_id":"444"
      },{
        "des": 'subchild des555',
        "sub_sub_id":"555"
      }]
    }, {
      "des": 'chile description12',
      "childid":"12",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des112',
        "sub_sub_id":"112"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "parentdes": "Parent description2",
    "parentid":"2",
    "childdes": [{
      "des": 'chile description21',
      "childid":"21",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des212',
        "sub_sub_id":"212"
      }]
    }, {
      "des": 'chile description22',
      "childid":"22",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des222',
        "sub_sub_id":"222"
      }]
    }]
  }];

var subIdsArray = [];

function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}

ObjectValues = function(v, k){
  if (typeof v == "object") {
    for (var kp in v) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(v, kp)) {
        ObjectValues(v[kp], k != undefined ? k + "." + kp : kp);
      }
    }
  } else {
    var currentString = k + ":" + v;
    if(currentString.indexOf('sub_sub_id:') !== -1)
    {
      var valueToArray = currentString.split("sub_sub_id:")[1];
      subIdsArray.push(valueToArray);
    }

  }
};

for (var i in data) {
  ObjectValues(data[i]);
}

for (var i in subIdsArray) {
  console.log(subIdsArray[i]);
}

//subIdsArray = ["111","444","555","112","212","222"]
```

Just fetch the id from the user's input and using it check the keys in the array (if the id exists, check the previous and next keys).

Comment: Look at your working solution its not printing as per expected but yes I have to admin this one good logic to find out.

Comment: @subhra why? `"111","444","555","112","212","222"` is exactly the order of sub id's in your data (from both of the objects in the original array)